# Degree Symbol not displayed in CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have coordinates in a Pandas Data Frame
In my pd DF, the coordinates look like: `3° 51' 9" E`

However, after exporting to CSV, I get it like `3¬∞ 51' 9" E`

How can I keep the `°` symbol?

I use the pandas.to_csv function to write to my csv and I tried adding the argument `encoding = 'utf-8'` but it is not working.

How can I do it?

In TextEdit, the `°` displays properly. When switching to Excel it does not.

Comment: What are you using to view the CSV?

Comment: Excel. Also in TextEdit the  ° symbol displays correctly

Comment: Then it's not a problem of pandas but excel...

Comment: Do you know how to solve it ? I can't find anything online

Answer (score 1):

Textedit and Excel have different default ways of using unicode, which is why the characters look different.

The [default pandas output](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is `ascii` in python2 and `utf-8` in python 3. You can modify either that, or [excel](http://www.lukemiller.org/journal/2005/03/changing-default-text-import-origin.html), to see the degrees symbol.